# int * vs int [] vs int (*)[] in function parameters. Which one should I use?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

In the C-programming language there are many different ways to declare the parameter of a function that takes an array as an argument passed through a pointer.

I have prepared an example that shows you what I mean. It is an implementation of the `std::accumulate` function in C++. It is a function that performes addition of all elements in an array and returns the result.

I can write it like this:

```
int accumulate(int n, int *array)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This can also be written to this (which means the exact same thing):

```
int accumulate(int n, int array[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I can also write it like this:

```
int accumulate(int n, int (*array)[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sum += (*array)[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

All these options are very similar and generate the same executable code but they have a slight difference which is how the caller passes the arguments.

This is how the first two versions gets called:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, -40, 23, 35};
    printf("%d\n", accumulate(ARRAY_LENGTH(a), a));
    return 0;
}
```

This is how the thrid version gets called:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, -40, 23, 35};
    printf("%d\n", accumulate(ARRAY_LENGTH(a), &a));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the third option requires to user to explicitly specify the address of `a` with `&a`. The first two options does not require this because arrays implicitly gets converted into pointers to the same type in C.

I have always preferred the third approach.

This is why:

- It is more consistent with how other types are passed by pointers.

  ```
  int draw_point(struct point *p);

  int main()
  {
      struct point p = {3, 4};
      draw_point(&p); // Here is the 'address of' operator required.
  }
  ```
- It makes it possible to use macros like `ARRAY_LENGTH` to get the amount of elements in the array.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define ARRAY_LENGTH(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))

  void this_works(int (*array)[10])
  {
      /* This works! */
      printf("%d\n", ARRAY_LENGTH(*array));
  }

  void this_is_invalid_and_dangerous(int array[10])
  {
      /* This does NOT work because `array` is actually a pointer. */
      printf("%d\n", ARRAY_LENGTH(array));
  }
  ```

The only advantage I see with `int array[]` (and `int *array`) over `int (*array)[]` is that you get to write `array[X]` instead of `(*array)[X]` when you wish to grab an index.

But because I am not a professional I will ask you which version you prefer.

**When do you use what? What are the reasons to choose one of these options over another?**

I have mostly used `int (*array)[N]` but I see that the other two approaches are quite common as well.

Comment: I'm not yet happy with either answer.  They neither of them mention `pointer to array` — which is the defining difference between `int array[]` (which is effectively `int *` in the context of a function argument list) and `int (*array)[]`.

Comment: @Jonathan If you (or someone else) have something to add you can make a new answer that I will accept if it is better. Maybe I accepted an answer to early this time which discourages new answers from showing up. When I look back at this question I also realize that it may be too "opinion based" for this Q&A site but go ahead and make a new answer if you think that the other answers are missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used as function parameters, `int array[]` and `int *array` are same. You can use either. It is matter of taste.  `int (*array)[]` is tedious and not used widely.

`int (*array)[n]` is used most widely when 2D array is passed to a function. In that case you can access the element of array as `array[i][j]`.

Comment: Not really an answer. The first part of your answer is already stated in the question. And then, this question is not about 2D arrays ... and no, `int accumulate(int n, int (*array)[])` is not sufficient to be able to use `array[i][j]`. For that, you have to put the `n` in: `int (*array)[n]`.

Comment: @JensGustedt; Your point is valid. I made some correction. But, to me this question is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer the third variant, but it is not very commonly used. If so, with C99 I would write:

```
int accumulate(size_t n, int (*array)[n]) { ....
```

such that `sizeof *array` works in all cases inside the function.

Comment: Are you talking about two dimensional arrays? So sizeof knows the row length?

Comment: @haccks, no, the `[*]` is only for the prototype of the function, for the case that the names of the parameters aren't available. To really know `sizeof *array` the compiler has to see the real expression, and it is the one of the function definition that is evaluated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, no I am not talking about 2D arrays, here. This is one dialect to pass a pointer to a one dimensional array and to know the size of the array inside the function.

Comment: @JensGustedt; You are right. Its for prototype only.